# Using Dovecot LMTP as LDA

Tags: email, openldap, postfix-mta, dovecot, lmtp

I am trying to set up a postfix mail server with dovecot as MDA.
According to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot) link to set up dovecot to use LMTP I have done the following config.

## postfix

main.cf

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

master.cf

```
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}
```

## dovecot

dovecot.conf

```
protocols = imap lmtp
```

10-mail.conf

```
mail_privileged_group = mail
```

10-master.conf

```
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    mode = 0600
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
  }
  # Create inet listener only if you can't use the above UNIX socket
  #inet_listener lmtp {
    # Avoid making LMTP visible for the entire internet
    #address =
    #port = 
  #}
}
```

The mailboxes will be present in user's home directory `/users/<username>`
As stated by the link `/users` is the home directory of `vmail` user.
However with this config when I try to send mail like:

`mail -s "subj" username`

The mail bounces saying 

`warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=<uid>/<gid>: create maildir file ~username/Maildir/tmp/<tmp file>: Permission denied`

The ownership of `~username` is `vmail:vmail`
However the mail is successfully sent when the ownership is changed to `<user>:<group>` for each user.
How can I get this thing working with the mail directory ownership kept as `vmail:vmail` ?

Note: I am not trying to set up SASL as of yet.
I am just tryin

Comment: deliver and lmtp are differnent mechanisms

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ownership users and groups using below mentioned command.

example:-

```
chown -R user:group /path/to/file
```

-R --> recursive option

Comment: This is not something I desire. Since for every new user I will need to do that.